# How to query from the DB by age in Django when birthday is stored as year/month/day fields

Tags: python, django

I have some code to filter and sort by age, that previously worked off of the assumption that the model we are querying over stored age as a single integer.  These are the types of calls I was making:

```
user_profiles = user_profiles.filter(age__gte=min_age, age__lte=max_age)
user_profiles.order_by("age")
```

As part of a refactor, I've changed my model to store the birth year/month/day rather than a static age.  It's not clear to me how the querying calls should be translated to account for this, though.. If I want to query users between 14-20 years of age, how is this accomplished in Django when you need to combine the results of 3 disjoint columns?

Comment: That was the wrong change to make. You should have used a DateField rather than three separate integer fields.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you're open to refactoring, I strongly recommend turning the birthdate into a single `DateField` rather than using three separate columns. Then you can do something like this:

```
from datetime import date
from django.utils.timezone import now

def age_range(min_age, max_age):
    current = now().date()
    min_date = date(current.year - min_age, current.month, current.day)
    max_date = date(current.year - max_age, current.month, current.day)

    return user_profiles.filter(birthdate__gte=max_date,
                                birthdate__lte=min_date).order_by("birthdate")
```

Most databases (not to mention Django) have built-in support for date and time fields, so it makes sense to use those when possible.