# Compare datetime with Django birthday objects

Tags: python, django, datetime

I have a question about my script. I want to know all people who have more than 16 years from my Database. I want to check this when user triggers the function.

I have this function :

```
def Recensement_array(request) :

    date = datetime.now().year
    print date # I get year from now

    birthday = Identity.objects.values_list('birthday', flat=True) # Return list with all birthday values

    for element in birthday :
        if date - element < 117 : 
            print "ok < 117"

        else : 
            print "ok > 117"
```

From `print date` I get :

`2017`

From `print birthday` I get :

```
<QuerySet [datetime.date(1991, 12, 23), datetime.date(1900, 9, 12), datetime.date(1900, 9, 12), datetime.date(1900, 9, 12), datetime.date(1900, 9, 12), datetime.date(1089, 9, 22), datetime.date(1900, 9, 12), datetime.date(1900, 9, 12), datetime.date(1089, 9, 22), datetime.date(1089, 9, 22), datetime.date(1089, 9, 22), datetime.date(1089, 9, 22), datetime.date(1990, 12, 12)]>
```

So my goal is to substract date with birthday and compare if `date - birthday = 16 years`, I print element, else nothing.

I get two problems :

- How extract only `year` from `birthday` ?
- Then the comparison method is between `int` and `tuple` up to now. If I could extract only year from birthday, it should work right ?

Thank you

**EDIT :**

For example I want to get all people who had 16 years old since the begining of this year or will get 16 years old before the first year :

```
def Recensement_array(request) :

    today = datetime.now()
    age_16 = (today - relativedelta(years=16))

    result = Identity.objects.filter(birthday__range=[age_16, today]).order_by('lastname')

    paginator = Paginator(result, 3)
    page = request.GET.get('page', 1)

    try:
        result = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        result = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        result = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    context = {
    "Identity":Identity,
    "age_16":age_16,
    "datetime" : datetime,
    "result" : result,
    "PageNotAnInteger":PageNotAnInteger,
    }


    return render(request, 'Recensement_resume.html', context)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to query from the DB by age in Django when birthday is stored as year/month/day fields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25474545/how-to-query-from-the-db-by-age-in-django-when-birthday-is-stored-as-year-month)

Comment: @Sayse It doesn't solve my problem or I don't understand between your link and my problem

Comment: " I want to know all people who have more than 16 years from my Database." - It does exactly what you state

Comment: [Another duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34772465/1324033)

Comment: You don't actually want to just compare the years, since that would be mostly inaccurate (think of someone whose birthday is in December, you would report him as being a year older than he actually is). You want to compare the dates, and take the year from that comparison.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Yes it's exactly what I want to do. I edited my question with my script. Thanks to sayse for links. But I have to take account the first day of current year less 16 years right ?

Comment: With your current queryset you'll get people with age less than 16. To query people older than 16 years old you should change `range` to `lte`. In other words you'll query all people who was born 16 years ago or earlier. Try this `result = Identity.objects.filter(birthday__lte=age_16).order_by('lastname')`

Comment: @neverwalkaloner Thanks for your answer but if I want only people who have 16 years old or will get 16 years old up to the end of year ? I'm making a census process. For example get all people who have or will have 16 years during 2017. Then 2018, ...

Comment: @Valentin oh, I see now. Then try use `__year`: `result = Identity.objects.filter(birthday__year=age_16.year).order_by('last‌​name')` this will give you all records with birthday in specific year.

Comment: @neverwalkaloner I apologize if you didn't understand my view, when English is not your native langage, some aspects could be hard to explain. And your query works perfectly fine ! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need filter records with some specific year you can just use `__year` method of date field:

```
age_16 = (today - relativedelta(years=16))
result = Identity.objects.filter(birthday__year=age_16.year).order_by‌​('last‌​name')
```

Comment: As I said previously, it works well. I can get a list of 16 year-old people for 2017. People who already had 16 years old and people who will get 16 years old before the 31th December 2017